# Gremlin Python - How to get ID from valueMap

Tags: python, gremlin, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

I am fetching all the values from my graph into a list called nodes:

```
nodes = g.V().valueMap(True).toList()
```

For each node, I would like to get the id but I don't know how. E.g. I have a field called `'name'`. To get name of the first vertex I would do something like this:

```
nodes[0][‘name’]
```

But I can't get the id of the first node using the same way. I don't know why. Maybe since it is automatically assigned and not a user created field, there is a different way of fetching it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import id enum.

```
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T

nodes = g.V().valueMap(True).toList()

nodes[0][T.id]
```